# Android Volley JSON parse exception

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to build a Login page using volley on Android.
The request is working fine with GET, but I'm getting an error with POST.
I've looked into many similar questions here but none solved my issue.

My java code :

```
    final String username = user_name.getText().toString();
    final String password = pass_word.getText().toString();

    String url = "http://192.168.2.6/api_test/login.php";
    final StringBuilder resp = new StringBuilder();
    resp.append("Response: ");

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.show();
    //RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                resp_txt.setText("Response is : " + response.toString());

            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                resp_txt.setText("Error");
            }
            pDialog.hide();
        }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            resp_txt.setText(error.toString());
            pDialog.hide();
    }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
```

And my php code :

```
    class response{
public $name = "";
    }
    $e = new response();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM users  where    username='$username' and password='$password'");
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $e->name = $row["name"];
    echo json_encode($e);
    }
    } 
    else{
    echo "false";
     }
```

Error I'm getting is :

```
    ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted into JSON object.
```

It works perfectly with GET.

Comment: from RestClient plugin for firefox(or chrome) can you post the same values to http://192.168.2.6/api_test/login.php and check what result you get? I suppose, you are getting html response instead of json response

Comment: I did it several times already and I'm getting a valid JSON response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170496/error-parsing-data-org-json-jsonexception-value-br-of-type-java-lang-string-ca)

Comment: I mean using the Restclient send a request to the url as a POST request and fetch the response, as your error indicates `Value <br of` by which i see that a `<br>` tag comes in response which indicates you are not getting a json but a html response.

Comment: yes I did what you're saying. A POST request using the chrome plugin and I'm getting a JSON response that is also valid.

Comment: seems like you should give up with programming(or learn some basics - not copy and paste) ... problem is so obvious:  `$_POST[name]` is for what content type? .... `JsonObjectRequest` sends what content type? `Value <br of` means that you are getting an error on PHP side ...

Comment: try explaining a bit please?

Comment: Simple English --> "Hey brov, your response have" `<br` surely starting the response or within the Tags. Debug your `PHP code better`

Comment: ok.. for now send the same request as `StringRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`. Print the string response and check the result. You should see the error !!
Based on your confidence, that the restclient provides correct data but not in volley makes me think that there is a problem in request payload you send to server. Let me know what you get when you use `StringRequest`